# sending file telegram bot VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, telegram-bot

please help, I want to send a file (android.apk) from the bot telegram to the user, but the file the user received is not in the format (apk), how do I resolve this. I use vb.net and the Telegram.Bot library. this my code:

```
Public Async Function sendMessageFile(ByVal destID As String, ByVal Path As String, Optional ByVal 
       DescriptionFile As String = "") As Task

    Try

        Dim objReader As StreamReader
        Dim objFS As FileStream
        Dim errorf As String = ""
        Try
            If File.Exists(Path) Then
                objFS = New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open)
                objReader = New StreamReader(objFS)
                Await bott.SendDocumentAsync(destID, objFS, DescriptionFile)
                objReader.Close()
                objFS.Close()
                objReader.Dispose()
                objFS.Dispose()
                objFS = Nothing
                objReader = Nothing
            Else
                errorf = "File not found!"
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            errorf = ex.Message
        End Try

    Catch e As Exception
        log("sendMessageFile - " & e.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

'// this code sending file to user

```
Case "/download"
                    Await bott.SendChatActionAsync(ID, Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ChatAction.UploadDocument)
                    Const file As String = "C:\Resources\debug.apk"
                    Await sendMessageFile(ID, file, "TESTING")
```

'// screenshoot

https://prnt.sc/qf09sn

Comment: What's the use of `objReader`? You never do anything with it. What actions is `SendDocumentAsync()` performing? Are you sending the file as string, by chance? Don't call both `Close()` and `Dispose()`. Pick one (pick `Dispose()`) or, better, initialize the Stream with a `Using` statement. Setting these objects to `null` (`Nothing`) is not useful.

Comment: If you have to send the file as a string, you have to Base64 encode it, then of course decode it on the receiver's end.

Comment: Thank you for entering, is there a simple code sample?